# Log into my app using WSO2IS login page

Tags: authentication, wso2, wso2-identity-server

I'm working with WSO2 Identity Server 5.3.0 (it's installed on a VM in a server).

So, I would access to my application using WSO2IS login page.
I've already set the Service Provider by Management Console.
I've not set the IdP because I've thought that must be the Resident one.
It's enought like thta? Should I modify some files?
I cannot find the related page on the Documentation.
Hope to be clear.

After doing all, the /authenticationendpoint/login.do doesn't returns the possibility to introduce username and password.

Edit:
@Bee I add here the screenshot
[image]
and this is my url:

> http://myurl:9763/authenticationendpoint/login.do?response_type=code&scope=openid&client_id=my_clientID&redirect_uri=/myuri/

Answer (score 1):

Here you have multiple options. You can use either basic auth, OpenID Connect, SAML SSO, Federated authentication etc to authenticate to your app. Some useful links are below.

https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS530/Authentication
https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS530/Basic+Client+Profile+with+Playground
https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS530/Writing+a+Web+Service+Client+for+Authentication+and+User+Admin+Services
https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS530/Authenticators+and+Provisioning+Connectors

Comment: thank you so much! So, once that I have set the Resident IdP (I want WSO2IS as Identity Provider), it's set the SP (that is actually the link to my application) enough ?

Comment: Yes, you only have to configure SP.

Comment: I have done all, and yes, my app return to my app's login page. But it shows only 'SIGN IN'!! Did you know why doesn't appears the fields for username and password? And how can I do for make it possible? @Bee

Comment: can you share a screenshot?

Comment: Do you see any errors in the logs? Can you try in a private browser window too?

Comment: no, there is no error, the server returns to me: ''  "GET /myuri/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0 ''. I've tryed to change the 'localhost' name in /etc/hosts file renaming it as 'wso2.is' (as the guides saids), but  returns error. is it possible that is the response_type the error?

Comment: 302 means `GET /myuri/` is not deployed properly.

Comment: sooo.. how can I fix it? it's the wrong wndpoint or something else? I would that in myuri appears the wso2 login page